# Services in Android Lollipop seem to randomly disappear without error

Tags: java, android, android-activity, service, android-studio

I have a service running in an app that detects if the proximity sensor on the device is triggered or not.

However, when I'm testing on a device running Android Lollipop, the service seems to unexpectedly quit when I run other apps.

For example, I start my service:

```
Intent service = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ProximityService.class);
startService(service);
```

And then I close the app and allow it to run.
Next I open Google Chrome. I trigger the sensor by covering the proximity sensor. The service then suddenly disappears without a log or error message.

This has also occurred when I tried opening other apps such as the Camera app and games.

Is there a possible explanation for this erroneous behavior?

What could be causing these anomalies?

Comment: what is your service code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is within the range of **expected** behavior, and always has been, even if actual occurrences of it have not always been frequent.

The only "error" is in your expectation that Android will keep a background Service running - **no such promise is made**.

There is generally an effort made to restart a Service which is categorized as having work yet to do, at such a time as the system can support it.  But restarting the Service to finish the interrupted work is a very different thing from always letting it continue to run.

Comment: So the reason the Service is being killed is because the system cannot support it? - Also, the frequency of my service disappearing is quite high for some reason. I can almost consistently expect my service to disappear once I open these other processes.